# Calculating age by subtracting dates and showing it in DD/MM/YYYY format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to subtract 2 days from each other and display it in YYMMDD.

E.g.

```
2016-05-27 (Minus) 2015-01-15 = 1 Years, 5 Months, 16 Days
```

The two dates are in `DATETIME` format.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Dates do not have formats, they are binary. `DATEFORMAT` applies only to formatting/parsing strings and should be avoided. You may have any number of problems, eg using strings instead of dates, using an inappropriate string format, using the wrong function. Please post the code. In any case, there is *no* type that can return a time span in the way you ask

Comment: I tried various combinations using DATEDIFF and DATEADD but it will always run over, e.g. 91 days and not e.g. 1day 3 Months. If this is making sense?

Comment: @Noost there's no runover, that's the expected result. You are asking about age calculation, not the difference between two dates. You can't calculate age from the date difference - in your example, how long is each month? 28,29,30 or 31 days? How long is that 1 year? Obviously, it depends on leap years, the calendar used etc. There *are* a lot of relevant SO questions and many techniques, as it's not straighforward to calculate age in SQL

Comment: @Panagiotis, thanks for the help thus far. I do realise this is not straight forward as I do indeed need age calculation. I will check out the duplicate above. Thanks

Comment: @Noost remember, 4 years ago Azure crashed because someone added 365 to a certificate date instead of 1 year. You may want to do the calculations on the client side,e g.  using and appropriate Calendar class or library

Answer (score 1):

I think this works.

```
SELECT Cast(DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2015-01-15', '2016-05-27') as varchar(25)) + ' Years, '
    + Cast(DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-01-15', '2016-05-27') % 12 as varchar(25)) + ' Months, '
    + Cast(DATEDIFF(DAY, Dateadd(Month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-01-15', '2016-05-27')  % 12 ,Dateadd(Year, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2015-01-15', '2016-05-27'), '2015-01-15')), '2016-05-27') as varchar(25)) + ' Days'
```

Result:

```
1 Years, 4 Months, 12 Days
```

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

> DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

Then get the date with the number of Days

Then you can use `DATEADD` to add this number of Days.

`SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, startdate, enddate))`

Comment: Hi, tried your code, this is the result:                                                                    Date1: 2015-08-01 00:00:00.000                                                                 Date2: 2016-01-25 13:45:01.437                                                                        Days1: 1900-06-27 00:00:00.000                                                 MONTH: 1900-01-06 00:00:00.000                                                            YEAR: 1900-01-02 00:00:00.000

Comment: @Noost make sure you use the `datetime2` type instead of `datetime`. 0 for datetime is 0001-01-01 while 0 for datetime is 1900-01-01. This is a clever hack in any case that doesn't account for leap years. You are asking about age calculation and you can't do that with a simple DATEDIFF

Answer (score 0):

Try this query...

```
 select (datediff(dd,convert(datetime,'5/5/2014',101),getdate())/365) years, 
((datediff(dd,convert(datetime,'5/5/2014',101),getdate()) % 365)/30) months, 
((datediff(dd,convert(datetime,'5/5/2014',101),getdate()) % 365)%30) days
```

---

Result

```
years   months  days
1        10      1
```

Comment: Very close, the calcs are still wrong but I'll play some more with your script.